# Is it possible to offer a different billing method than google play in my android app (dating app)?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-billing

Inside my dating app is it possible to offer a different billing method than google play? I ask because I heard that now it's forbidden to offer anything else than google play billing but I see close to all app (tinder, etc.) are still offering their own credit card payment

Answer (score 0):

Only if it fulfils the requirements here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738?hl=en

Here are the exceptions:

> Developers offering products within a game downloaded on Google Play or providing access to game content must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment.
> Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded on Google Play must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment, except for the following cases:
> Payment is solely for physical products
> Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).
> In-app virtual currencies must only be used within the app or game title for which they were purchased.
> Developers must not mislead users about the apps they are selling nor about any in-app services, goods, content, or functionality offered for purchase. If your product description on Google Play refers to in-app features that may require a specific or additional charge, your description must clearly notify users that payment is required to access those features.
> Apps offering mechanisms to receive randomized virtual items from a purchase (i.e. "loot boxes") must clearly disclose the odds of receiving those items in advance of purchase.

Here are some examples of products not currently supported by Google Play In-app Billing:

> Retail merchandise, such as groceries, clothing, housewares, and electronics.
> Service fees, including taxi and transportation services, cleaning services, food delivery, airfare, and event tickets.
> One-time membership fees or recurring dues, including gym memberships, loyalty programs, or clubs offering accessories, clothing, or other physical products.
> One time-payments, including peer-to-peer payments, online auctions, and donations.
> Electronic bill payment, including credit card bills, utilities, and cable or telecommunications services.

Comment: thanks user14678216 but as far as i know Tinder (dating app) must offer google play billing payment, so why they do not do ?

Comment: Can the purchase be consumed outside of the app itself?

Comment: for tinder, I think they also have a website where you can consume the product

Comment: Yes so that is why. "except for the following cases: [...] Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players)."